# Why does the app launch when the device is connected?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, when connecting a USB device, the user requests permission to operate this device. And this happens every time a device is connected. This will annoy the user. I did the following: I created a file device_filter.xml, in which I entered the data about the device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="some_vendor_id" product-id="some_product_id" />
</resources>
```

And in MainActivity.cs indicated the following attributes:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached })]
[MetaData(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached, Resource = "@xml/device_filter")]
```

It worked. Now it requests access only on the first connection, but at the same time, the following happens now: when the device is connected, my application starts, if it was not started. How to fix it?

Comment: Because you have added an intent filter to the bootstrap-up activity in the manifest file to specify the Vendor-ID and product-ID of the USB device, as long as this type of USB device is connected, the system will pop up to open the specified application.

Comment: So. If I try to remove the attribute with this file, then the application will start asking for permission again every time the device is connected.

Comment: This also seems reasonable, because if you don't set a specific vid, it can't be sure that the same device is connected every time, so you need to apply for permission every time.

Comment: What can you advise me in this case?

Comment: Because of this design, if you don't want to request permissions every time, I think you might want to have root permission or modify the source code, but that's not recommended.